# Successor for spring boot integrated java shell ('CRaSH') in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-shell

As the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html) states the crasshd will be removed in spring boot 2.0.

What will be the replacement?

Answer (score 4):

The previous shell you mentions was a port inside spring-boot 1 and it seems not very active.

In spring Boot 2.0 you can use the [spring-shell](https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell) that you can use in an existing spring-boot app or a specific spring-boot shell that can be deployed as standalone.

After, which option to take would depends on your needs.

On my side, I just created a specific shell for publishing messages in ActiveMQ, you get the whole power of Spring-Boot for automatic configuration of any connectivity with external systems (JMS, JDBC, LDAP, SMTP, etc...).

For doing this, I just added the following pom dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

in my Spring Boot project.

Note that I was able to integrate it in Spring Boot 1.5.15 and 2.1.2 RELEASES.

Answer (score 1):

There is no replacement to be provided by the Spring team.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7044

> Sorry, not at the moment. Based on the stats we have, it would appear that the remote shell isn't very widely used. For example, comparing Maven Central downloads for August, the remote shell starter had 2% of the downloads that the web starter had. That means that it's unlikely to be worth investing significant effort in a replacement.

There is a third party replacement, from the ticket,

https://github.com/anand1st/sshd-shell-spring-boot